# Visible Edit Shortcut for WordPress menu that uses nav walker

Tags: theme-customizer

I am working on a WordPress theme. In the main navigation menu I had to use the following code to apply Bootstrap4 styles on the menu items (from [here](https://github.com/mebishalnapit/bootstrap-navwalker/)).

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'theme-textdomain' ),
) );

// Now, you can display the menu in your theme via below PHP code addition in the header.php file of your theme.

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_html_e( 'Toggle Navigation', 'theme-textdomain' ); ?>">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                'container'      => false,
                'depth'          => 2,
                'menu_class'     => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                'walker'         => new Bootstrap_NavWalker(),
                'fallback_cb'    => 'Bootstrap_NavWalker::fallback',
            ) );
            ?>
        </div>
</nav>
```

If I dont use the nav-walker the edit shortcut is visible and works for the navigation menu.
[image]

But, when I use the nav-walker the button goes away.

I tried adding this code in customiser

```
 $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial('primarymenu', array(
        'selector' => '#site-navigation',
        'render_callback' => 'asensio_customize_partial_primarymenu',
    ));
```

This has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Nav menus in will use selective refresh by default when they are output into the page via `wp_nav_menu()` but with a few restrictions on the arguments. For the exact requirements on the `$args`, see [`WP_Customize_Nav_Menus::filter_wp_nav_menu_args()`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/770834cc4c8a5469cd1f465f53998147e083945e/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-nav-menus.php#L1240-L1262).

In short, if you're using a custom walker, then you need to pass it as a class name string instead of as an instantiated object. For example, instead of:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    // ...
    'walker' => new My_Custom_Walker(),
) );
```

Do this instead:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    // ...
    'walker' => 'My_Custom_Walker',
) );
```

Comment: this is a bug, not a feature :( all it means is that a dummy classes needs to be created to wrap an instantiated walker which is a pointless undocumented bummer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Your solution arises this error

`Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php:199 Stack trace: #0`

...and in bunch of other files, too long to post in a comment.

Comment: @MarkKaplun It's not pointless. The limitation is there because we need to be able to serialize the `$args` to JSON in order to be passed in the partial refresh request.

Comment: We could help guide usage by checking of `walker` is not a string and then calling `_doing_it_wrong()` to advise passing a string instead.

Comment: @ShafayatAlam It's not possible to advise without being able to see the full to the custom walker code you're using.

Comment: @MarkKaplun also, the requirement of using a string `walker` instead of an object _is_ documented in the dev note: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/29/fast-previewing-changes-to-menus-in-the-customizer/

Comment: @WestonRuter, sorry should have clearer. It is pointless in the sense that it requires some code that is purely automatic and requires "zero thinking". This probably can be done by core . Or the other way to look at it is that passing instantiated object is "soft" deprecated and there should be a notice at least when `wp_debug` is on.... especially since there is a constant move the admin focus to the customizer. in which case it should be made easier for developer to know when they are writting sub optimal code

Comment: This solution works in combination with this solution.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/295475/24599